# Query three tables result into one row

Tags: mysql

Table 1 - users

```
------------
id  | name
------------
 1  | foobar
 2  | barfoo
```

Table 2 - locations

```
-------------
id | loc_name
-------------
 1 | Location1
 2 | Location2
 3 | Location3
 4 | Location4
```

Table 3 - users_location

```
-----------------
user_id | loc_id
-----------------
 1      | 3
 1      | 4
 2      | 1
 2      | 2
```

The output that I'm looking for is this one

```
-------------------------------
name    | loc_name
-------------------------------
 foobar | Location3,Location4
 barfoo | Location1,Location2
```

Currently here is the code I got

```
SELECT users.name,locations.loc_name
FROM users
JOIN users_location ON users_location.user_id = users.id
JOIN locations ON locations.id = users_location.loc_id
```

Here is my current output:

```
----------------------
 name   | loc_name  
----------------------
 foobar | Location3
 foobar | Location4
 barfoo | Location1
 barfoo | Location2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get your expected result:

```
SELECT US.name, GROUP_CONCAT(LO.loc_name) AS loc_name
FROM users AS US
JOIN users_location AS UL ON UL.user_id = US.id
JOIN locations AS LO ON LO.id = UL.loc_id
GROUP BY US.name;
```

Also you can use table alias `users AS US`, for better readability.

---

As per the comments, for any separator other than comma, you may use `[SEPARATOR str_val]` also [`ORDER BY`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) will ensure the expected output in the ascending or descending order.

Sample code for hyphen as separator:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(LO.loc_name ORDER BY LO.loc_name SEPARATOR '-') AS loc_name
```

Comment: I am deleting my answer (https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/233433/877) and upvoting yours since they are essentially the same.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just a question I'm thinking is there a way to change the commas between the locations, Like a hypen or something?

Comment: Yes. Can you please try `GROUP_CONCAT(LO.loc_name SEPARATOR '-')`

Comment: The [ORDER BY](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) might also be useful for clarity?